# $.Deferred vs new $.Deferred

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

What is the difference between

```
var dfd = new $.Deferred
```

and

```
var dfd = $.Deferred
```

In which cases you need to use new vs not using it?

Comment: I think this is muddied a bit by the behavior of `new`. In particular `new` allows invoking a function without requiring parentheses, so `new $.Deferred` is a shorthand for `new $.Deferred()`. Assigning `$.Deferred` to a variable on the other hand is simply aliasing the original function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These two are not equal, one creates a diferred object while another creates an alias

```
var dfd = new $.Deferred
```

It create a a deferred object instance, for creating an new instance there is no need to use new keyword - you can just say `var dfd = $.Deferred()`

```
var dfd = $.Deferred
```

It create an alias for the type `$.Deferred`

So I don't see any need to use the second format in anywhere, expect for if you want to create a shortcut. You can use the first format to create a new instance of deferred object

Comment: @downvoter don't confuse between `$.Deferred()` and `$.Deferred` they are not equal

Comment: I've never seen `$.Deferred` used as a constructor, always as a factory. I admit it makes more sense with `new`, though.

Comment: @JanDvorak still I think the preferred way is to use it as a factory method

Comment: APJ, I wonder if this might be a good place to state what is returned by all four possibilities; `new $.Deferred`, `new $.Deferred()`, `$.Deferred`, `$.Deferred()`. As it stands, your answer provides 75% of the information. Just needs the last 25%, and presentation in list form or one para per possibility.

Comment: What is the use case btw them, how will it affect how you use them?

Answer (score 11):

[jQuery official documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20150307015748/http://api.jquery.com:80/jquery.deferred/) says:

> "The jQuery.Deferred() constructor creates a new Deferred object. The new operator is optional."

So I guess usage wise, there is not going to be any difference whether you create a new object from Deferred or use it as it is.

Comment: You answered the question he _should_ have asked. Namely if the second example had been `var dfd = $.Deferred()`.  That's a more interesting comparison, and your answer would have been correct. Except the second example in the actual question is nonsense **without the parentheses**, and hardly ever useful.

Answer (score 6):

### These are identical:

```
var dfd1 = $.Deferred();
var dfd2 = new $.Deferred;
var dfd3 = new $.Deferred();
```

Each creates a new [Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) object.  `new`is optional because $.Deferred is a [factory function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14172862/673991).

### This is probably nonsense:

```
var wtf = $.Deferred;
```

As @ArunPJohny pointed out, it just aliases the factory function. It does not create a Deferred object.