# Inherit the prototype

Tags: javascript

Having the parent *class*:

```
function Animal() {
  // do something
}

Animal.prototype.walk = function() {
  alert('I am walking.');
};
```

and the child *class*:

```
function Lion() {
  // do something
}
```

if I want the `Lion` to inherit `Animal`'s prototype a common practice is this:

```
Lion.prototype = new Animal();

// Set the constructor to Lion, because now it points to Animal
Lion.prototype.constructor = Lion;
```

**Is this in any way different from this (as result not as performance)?**

```
$.extend(Lion.prototype, Animal.prototype);
```

For non jquery developers: [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) copies all the prototype methods and attributes, one by one from Animal to Lion.

I am not a big expert of inheritance in javascript. I usually use an MVC framework for front-end development where everything just works, but now I would love to understand also how inheriting the prototype works.

**NOTE!**
I read many articles about the subject, I know there are many ["plugins"](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) that implements the *Class* functionality. This is **not** what I need. Please answer the question, not just link articles about the subject (except if that answers it).

Thank you!

Comment: `$.extend` in jQuery implements a **mixin** JavaScript pattern designed primarily to clone objects and add new props and methods; where modifying the former object doesn't affect the new one. Think of it as the new `Object.create` in Harmony, with one difference - `newObj = Object.create(oldObj)` makes `oldObj` the `__proto__` of the `newObj`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference, copying the properties between two prototypes doesn't make them "connected" to each other, i.e.:

```
$.extend(Lion.prototype, Animal.prototype);

// add one more method to the prototype
Animal.prototype.test = function() {
  alert('test');
};

var x = new Lion();
x.test(); // TypeError: Object <Lion> has no method 'test'
```

You wouldn't have this if you use `new Animal()` as the prototype for `Lion`, as demonstrated [here](http://jsbin.com/ibacen/1/).

Answer (score 3):

I recently wrote an article that explains [Why Prototypal Inheritance Matters](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/). It's a bit long but well worth the read.

To answer your question directly, yes `Lion.prototype = new Animal` is different from `$.extend(Lion.prototype, Animal.prototype)` because:

1. In the first case you're using [delegation](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/#delegation_or_differential_inheritance).
2. In the second case you're using [concatenation](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/#cloning_or_concatenative_inheritance).

The post I linked you to explains true prototypal inheritance (i.e. prototypal inheritance using the prototypal pattern).

This is how your program would look if you used true prototypal inheritance in JavaScript:

```
var animal = {
    create: function () {
        return this.extend();
    },
    walk: function () {
        alert("I am walking.");
    }
};

var lion = animal.extend({
    create: function () {
        return animal.create.call(this);
    }
});
```

Here the `extend` function is the one from the post I linked you to.

Contrast this with your code which uses the constructor pattern for prototypal inheritance.

Here's a fiddle which shows true prototypal inheritance in action: http://jsfiddle.net/6x4BU/

Comment: Nice article (though I don't share all of your views). At least, putting enumerable properties on `Object.prototype` is bad practise! And those `clones` arrays will prevent garbage collection.

Comment: @Bergi - That's a nice observation. I'll try to find a solution to that. Thank you.

Comment: @Bergi - Would you mind posting the same comment on my blog so that others may read it as well.

Answer (score 1):

No they are not the same.

The first example the Lion prototype becomes **an instance** of Animal. That instance does inherit from the Animal prototype and will link back to that prototype. *If the Animal prototype is modified the instance will be affected.*

The second example is simply **copying the properties** from the Animal prototype and Lion *will not be linked to the actual Animal prototype itself.*

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, yes there is a difference.

In the first example, changes to the Animal prototype will change the behavior of Lion instances.

In the second example, Lion inherits the capabilities of Animal **at the time of the $.extend()** call.

The first way has some possibly harmful side-effects, though, in particular:

- A change to Animal can ripple out and break Lion and its descendants. This dynamic changes property of delegate prototypes is usually considered a good thing, but when it's applied to multi-level inheritance, it frequently causes problems.
- The first method doesn't allow for **selective inheritance** from Animal. It's all or nothing. You wanted the banana, but what you got was the gorilla, the banana, and the entire jungle. (This famous problem is called the gorilla/banana problem). The latter method lets you selectively inherit from Animal: `$.extend(Lion.prototype, { run: Animal.prototype.run, sleep: Animal.prototype.sleep });`
- `instanceof` breaks with concatenation -- but `instanceof` is not reliable in any case. If you reassign the Animal prototype, it will break. If you try to use it across execution contexts, it breaks. In other words, **don't use `instanceof`**, regardless of which inheritance method you choose.

Constructor functions aren't necessary at all. You could just create an object literal called animal and do this:

```
lion = Object.create(animal);
```

Even better, put that in a factory function:

```
function lion(options) {
  return $.extend(Object.create(lion), options);
}
```

Factory functions have lots of advantages over constructor that I won't go into here. You can see more details in my answer on this post: [Constructor function vs Factory functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698726/constructor-function-vs-factory-functions)

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic prototype inheritance in pure JavaScript

```
// base class declaration
function Animal (arg) {
    this.arg = arg;
}

// just a method in the Animal class, it can be whatever you want
Animal.prototype.roar = function () {
    alert(this.arg);
};

// object that inherits the base class
function Lion (arg) {
    // the call to the super constructor
    Animal.call(this, arg);
}

// the prototypical inheritance
Lion.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
// the constructor needs to be set so that it does not show as the base constructor
// otherwise the constructor for all instances of Lion will show as Animal
Lion.prototype.constructor = Lion;

var symba = new Lion('the lion is roaring');

symba.roar();
```