# Difference between function and constructor function

Tags: javascript

I want to know the difference between function and constructor function.

**Normal function**

```
function = dosomething(){ //do something };
```

**Constructor Function**

```
function = Dosomething(){ //do something };
```

Why we keep the first letter capital in constructor function. Is there any specific reason behind it

Comment: Aside from a few native functions, all `function`s can be used as a constructor. The naming/capitalization is just a convention used to help describe those that are explicitly intended to be used as a constructor by their author.

Comment: Follow This Link [Constructor Function And Normal Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698726/constructor-function-vs-factory-functions)

Comment: *"Why we keep the first letter capital in constructor function. Is there any specific reason behind it"* Probably because constructors/classes are also capitalized any many other programming languages.

Comment: @RobG I was referring to native methods. [`"function slice() { [native code] } is not a constructor"`](http://jsconsole.com/?new%20Array.prototype.slice).

Comment: Ok, so perhaps all native functions and built–in function Objects, but not their methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are all the difference between function and constructor function in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401553/what-are-all-the-difference-between-function-and-constructor-function-in-javascr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference - Using the capital letter for the name is just a best practice when creating a Function that will act as a Constructor.

It's really how you treat the functions that make them behave differently.  This is because Functions are first class in Javascript.

For example:

```
function MyRegularFunction() {
   console.log("regular");
}
MyRegularFunction();


vs.


function MyObjectFunction() {
   console.log("ctor")
}

MyObjectFunction.prototype = {
    constructor: MyObjectFunction,
    myMethod: function() {
        console.log("object")
     }
}

var myInstance = new MyObjectFunction();
myInstance.myMethod();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Capitalizing the first letter in a constructor function is just a naming convention, indicating that the function is a class. An example of a constructor function would be:

```
function Car(color, make, model){
    this.color = color;
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
}
```

You would then instantiate the constructor function like so:

```
var Dodge = new Car("Blue", "Dodge", "Caliber");
```