# Aren't all JavaScript functions constructors as well?

Tags: javascript, eval

I am using `eval` function in a weird way, as a constructor.

```
try {
  var y = new eval()
} catch(error) {
    console.log("caught a " + error.name + ": " + error.message);
}
```

It throws error as,

```
caught a TypeError: function eval() { [native code] } is not a constructor
```

As the error message shows, eval is a function but not a constructor.

The question is, don't all javascript functions act as constructors as well?

Comment: eval is a reserved keyword / a native function. Dont mess with it.

Comment: No, some other notible exceptions are some _DOM_ methods and _arrow functions_ `x => undefined`

Comment: Agreed, eval is a built-in function.  If you  made your own `function myEval() {}` and then used that code it should be fine.

Comment: You may refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401553/what-are-all-the-difference-between-function-and-constructor-function-in-javascr) for better understanding between the difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not all functions are constructors.

Constructors are [function values with a [[Construct]] internal property](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-isconstructor), which not all functions have.  This is made explicit in [6.1.7.2 Object Internal Methods and Internal Slots](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#table-6) of the language spec:

> A function object is not necessarily a constructor and such non-constructor function objects do not have a [[Construct]] internal method.

Using `new` or `Reflect.construct` to call a non-constructor as a constructor throws a `TypeError`.

Comment: What are the practical implications of this?  If I write a javascript function, is it automatically tagged with this [[Construct]] internal method?

Comment: @JohnCarpenter, it depends on how the function is created.  As @PaulS points out above, creating a function using the arrow function syntax means it will not have the [[Construct]] property.  Using the `function` keyword will generally produce a construct-able function.

Comment: Huh, add this to the list of things that I didn't know that I didn't know.