# Meaning of keyword "new" in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I've read the topic about "new" keyword in javascript ([What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript)). But, i'm still in the fog; let's talk about this example :

```
var foo = function() {
    return {
        setA: function(a) {
            this.a = a;
        },
        readA: function() {
            console.log(this.a);
        }
    };
};
```

And now what's about these two pieces of code :

One:

```
var bob1 = foo();
bob1.setA(10);
bob1.readA();
```

Two:

```
var bob2 = new foo();
bob2.setA(10);
bob2.readA();
```

I cannot see any differences at my level. So what is the gain to use the keyword "new" ?

Comment: Related: [Constructor function vs Factory functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698726/constructor-function-vs-factory-functions)

Comment: I think it is related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript

Comment: @3506238: the OP has already read that.

Comment: BTW, the post you read before has a lot of useful information, you just need to scroll down to see some of the easier-to-understand answers. For example, this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1646957/2074608

Comment: The difference is in scope of the function. You don't see any difference because you don't refer to the `this` in the scope of the function. You only refer to the `this` in the scope of the returned object which is the same in both cases.

Comment: In the given example there is no difference, the advantage of creating new instances comes when you need to create new instances that can be changed and worked with without affecting other instances etc.

Comment: @MolecularMan: `this` is not the *scope*, it's the *context* of a function!

Comment: @Bergi I didn't say this=scope, did I?

Comment: @Bergi, yeah I meant context.

Comment: @MolecularMan: Oh right. Maybe in the first sentence; I expected "*The difference [between `new` and not] is what `this` is in the constructor function*". If you're just saying that he uses `this` in the wrong function, then yes.

Comment: @Bergi, yeah. What I meant wat that `this` refers to different objects when used as constructor and plain function, but wasn't able to pick wright words.

Answer (score 4):

If your function returns object directly, then you do not need an `new` operator.
The `new` keys does more than that.

Lets say

```
function Animal(kind, name) {
   this.kind = kind;
   this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype.walk = function() {
    console.log('Walking');
}
```

Then you are doing

```
 var animal = new Animal();
```

Javascript engine will do following things

```
  var o = Object.create(Animal.prototype)
  Animal.apply(o, arguments);
  return o;
```

`Object.create` will do the prototype inheritance of the `prototype` object of `Animal` function. So `animal` object will have its own properties and its inherited property.

Answer (score 3):

> i'm still in the fog about `new`; let's talk about this example :
>
> ```
> var foo = function() {
>     return {
>         setA: function(a) {
>             this.a = a;
>         },
>         readA: function() {
>             console.log(this.a);
>         }
>     };
> };
> ```

We shouldn't talk about this example. Whether or not we use `new` with this function does not make a difference, because of [the way `new` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new):

> 1. A new object is created, inheriting from `foo.prototype`.
> 2. The constructor function `foo` is called with the specified arguments and [`this` bound
>      to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
>      the newly created object.
> 3. The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result
>      of the whole new expression. If the constructor function doesn't
>      explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used
>      instead. (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can
>      choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation
>      process.)

Step 3 is the thing to look at here. You're creating and returning an object (the object literal), so that will become assigned to `bob1`. Usually, constructor functions do not `return` anything, and the new instance that is implicitly created in step1 (and available inside the function as `this`) becomes the result.

Both `new foo()` and `foo()` do only assign your object literal to the `bob` variable - no difference in the result. The instance created by the `new` is totally ignored by your code. It would be different in the following examples:

```
function foo() {
    this.setA = function(a) {
        this.a = a;
    };
    this.readA = function() {
        console.log(this.a);
    };
    // return this; is implicit
}
var bob = new foo; // OK
var bob = foo(); // horrible error
```

Answer (score 1):

If the constructor function `foo` returns an object, then `new foo()` is identical to calling the function `foo()` directly. We can prove this is so by examining the [ECMAScript behavior for `new`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.2):

> Return the result of calling the [[Construct]] internal method on *constructor* [i.e., the constructor function]...

The [`[[Construct]]` internal method](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2) of a function is a special wrapper for calling the function's `[[Call]]` internal method (which is just the function's normal behavior). Let's see the end of `[[Construct]]` to see how this wrapper behaves:

> 8) Let *result* be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal property of F *[the function invoked by `new`]*, providing *obj* as the `this` value and providing the argument list passed into [[Construct]] as args.
>
> 9) If Type(*result*) is Object then return *result*.
>
> 10) Return *obj*.

In your case, your constructor function `foo` returns an object, so step 9 of `[[Construct]]` (and therefore, in turn, `new foo()`) returns that object. But we see in step 10 that `[[Construct]]` *could* return some other value called *obj*, which is equal to the `this` value inside the constructor. Let's rewind and see what that's all about:

> 1) Let *obj* be a newly created native ECMAScript object.
>
> ...
>
> 4) Let *proto* be the value of calling the [[Get]] internal property of F with argument "`prototype`".
>
> 5) If Type(*proto*) is Object, set the [[Prototype]] internal property of *obj* to *proto*.

Here we see the real power of `new`: if the constructor function does not return an object (and therefore the `[[Construct]]` operation launched by `new` is allowed to return `obj`), then prototypal inheritance takes place. The `[[Prototype]]` of `obj` (a.k.a. `obj.__proto__`) is set to the `prototype` property of the constructor method. This means that if `foo` doesn't return an object (and instead modifies `this`), and `foo.prototype.someProp` is set, then an instance returned from `var instance = new foo()` will have access to `instance.someProp`.

Thus, a different way to write your code might be:

```
var foo = function() { };
foo.prototype.setA = function(a) { this.a = a; };
foo.prototype.setA = function(a) { console.log(this.a); };
```

In this case, `new foo()` produces an object whose prototype chain includes `foo.prototype`, while `foo()` does not. This has the benefit of lower memory use: all `foo` instances here share common prototypal methods, instead of having each instance carry its own separate functions.