# Using Object constructors that return objects. How it works?

Tags: javascript, oop

I've been always creating JS objects like this `a = {}` or this `a = new MyConstructor()` without thinking much about it.

Then I came up with some code that looks like this:

```
function Constructor(){
    var private = {
          a:1,
          b:2
    };
    return private;
}


var a = new Constructor();
```

`a` naturaly now contains a new instance of the `private` object. And then I realised that the `new` operator is not required because the `private` object gets created every time the `Constructor` function gets called.

So the *actual* question is: What happens when calling `new Constructor()`?

Why shouldn't just do `a = Constructor()` instead?

What happens to any public properties of the `Constructor` object if any?

Is returning objects from a constructor a bad idea?

Comment: [What is the 'new' keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript) might help.

Comment: Also relevant is [Constructor function vs Factory functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698726/constructor-function-vs-factory-functions) (you're actually talking about a *factory* function, not a constructor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What happens when calling `new Constructor()`?

Have a look at [the docs for the `new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) and the [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1646698/1048572) question.

An instance is created (like `Object.create(Constructor.prototype)`), which is accessible via `this` inside the `Constructor` function. However, the result of the call will only be the returned object (`private`), that is assigned to `a`.

> Why shouldn't just do `a = Constructor()` instead?

Actually, you should do this. `Constructor` is not a constructor, it doesn't create instances - it just returns the `private` object. Therefore, don't use `new`. However, you should also rename the function so that it is clear, e.g. to `makeXYZ()`.

> What happens to any public properties of the `Constructor` object if
>   any?

`a` and `b` are the "public" properties of the returned objects.
If you mean "static" properties on the `Constructor` function itself, nothing happens to them.
If you mean "shared" properties on the `Constructor.prototype` - nothing happens to them, they do not get inherited by the returned objects (which is probably not what was intended).

> Is returning objects from a constructor a bad idea?

From constructors, yes.
From functions in general, no. Make it a normal [factory function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) (i.e. a function that returns objects), which is a fine pattern.

Comment: So, the actual answer to the question is (according to the docs) `when a constructor returns a value, the object construction proccess is overridden`. Is that correct?

Comment: Somewhat, yes. The instance object is still created, and accessible as `this` inside the constructor as usual, but `a` will become only the `private` object that was returned.

Comment: That was the answer then :) If you add this in your answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

You faced with " NativeObject" javascript pattern.
It emulates some OOP paradigms like encapsulation, polymorphism, inheritance, abstraction and so on.

With "new" keyword you create new instance of the object, in JS it can be

```
var function_example = function() {
var privateField = 11;
var publicField = 22;

return {
publicField: publicField
}    
}
```

So, when you what to get object you can call this function:

```
var object = function_example();
```

If you want to get function as delegate and assign a reference to it, u can:

```
var function2_axample = function_example;
```

If you want to create new instance u should:

```
var instance = new function_example();
var publicValue = instance.publicField;
```

So, u can remember, in compare with OOP paradigm, it like this: function - it is class, new function - it is instance.