# If Functions can be reused as many times as needed why create new instances with "new" and "this"?

Tags: javascript

I'm sure that I'm missing something but I don't understand why developers so often create new instances of `Functions`.  For example I see this basic concept in numerous tutorials.

```
function Car(make, model, year) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
}

var myCar = new Car("Toyota", "Tacoma", 1997);
console.log(myCar.make +" " +myCar.model +" " +myCar.year);
```

But if functions can be reused as many times as needed why create new instances?

This function appears to do the same thing and I can use it as many times as needed.

```
function Car(make, model, year) {
    console.log(make +" " +model +" " +year);
}

car("Toyota", "Tacoma", 1997);
car("Honda", "Civic", 2005);
// etc etc...
```

Comment: Because sometimes you want to create objects. Sure, in your code that only logs some values and does nothing else, they're not necessary.

Comment: I realize that you likely asked the question in good faith, but this is almost certain to draw a @#!tstorm of conflicting opinions and semi-useless factoids like how V8 optimizes object creation with `new`. The short, short answer is that constructor functions are *never* necessary and *sometimes* convenient.

Comment: This is Javascript's original implementation of a class. It just happens to use a function for the constructor. It's a class instantiation vs a vanilla function call.

Comment: @NickWyman I'd say more [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698726/constructor-function-vs-factory-functions)

Comment: Are the downvotes really necessary? I VTC'd as dupe but its edge-casey. And it's a totally legit question and if you haven't been a JS dev then you probably don't know it's everyone's favorite dead horse to beat.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `new` keyword allows you to create *instances* of objects that you can then manipulate.

In your first example, you can change the model of the car (for instance) after you've created it with `myCar.model = "Carrera"`.

Answer (score 0):

By saying `new Car` the keyword new does three things:
1. Create a new object instance such as BobsCar.model("...");
2. Assign its prototype to the function’s .prototype | BobsCar.prototype.etc...
3. Apply the function with the object instance set as “this” | this.make = make;