# why we creating instance from events.EventEmitter(), and not for http?

Tags: node.js

Event Emitter

```
var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
```

Http Server Request

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){})
```

Creating instance for `new events.EventEmitter()` not for `http.createServer()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constructor function vs Factory functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698726/constructor-function-vs-factory-functions)

Answer (score 0):

The http library exports the `Server` constructor so just like with eventEmitters, you can do:

```
let server = new http.Server(fn);
```

This, is exactly the same way that you do things with the `events` library.

`http.createServer()` is a factory function. It creates a Server object for you.  It's not entirely obvious why they decided to also export a factory function, but you can use either the factory function or the constructor.  If you look at the code for `http.createServer()`, you can see that this is all it does:

```
function createServer(requestListener) {
  return new Server(requestListener);
}
```

where `Server` is the same thing as `http.Server`.  So, the `http` library just offers two ways of creating a server, one of which works exactly like the `events` library.