# ngrx: how to pass parameters to selector inside createSelector method

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a very simple state in my store:

```
const state = {
 records: [1,2,3],
};
```

I have a selector for records:

```
export const getRecords = createSelector(getState, (state: State) => state.records));
```

And what I want now is to have separate selectors for fetching each record by index.
For this purpose I want to create one generic selector with props in this way:

```
export const getRecordByIndex = createSelector(
getRecords,
(state: State, { index }) => state.records[index]),
);
```

And after that create a couple of specific selectors e. g.:

```
export const getFirstRecord = createSelector(
getRecordByIndex(/* somehow pass index = 0 to this selector */),
(firstRecord) => firstRecord),
);
```

But I didn't find any mention how to pass parameters to selectors with props when we use them inside createSelector method. Is it possible?

Answer (score 28):

From this blog post: https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/parameterized-selectors

> As of NgRx 6.1 selectors also accepts an extra props argument. Which
> means you can now define a selector as the following:

```
export const getCount = createSelector(
  getCounterValue, 
  (counter, props) => counter * props.multiply
);

this.counter = this.store.pipe(
  select(fromRoot.getCount, { multiply: 2 })
);
```

Ah ... but rereading your question, you are asking then how to build another selector that uses this selector? The above-linked article suggests building a factory function.

Comment: I feel so energetic because you shared a post of mine! :)
To answer the question: the props property drills down to other selectors inside the selector. In other words `getRecordByIndex`, also retrieves the `props` property as its last argument.

Comment: what does "building a factory function" exactly mean? @timdeschryver how does this help to pass a parameter to the selector (which may be determined by the selector implementation)?

Comment: @JFFIGK search on "Static parameter" in the above blog post. It has an example.

Comment: This may help: https://www.sitepoint.com/factory-functions-javascript/ (But OMG it has a bunch of popups!) Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698726/constructor-function-vs-factory-functions

Comment: The updated url for the blog post: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/ngrx-parameterized-selector-e3f610529f8

Comment: The blog post doesn't exist anymore on medium. You can find it here: https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/parameterized-selectors

Comment: @DeborahK I have selectors defined at feature level that are then "exposed" globally in a "shared.ts". I'm trying to create selectors with props but have an issue that I'm not sure how to get around with my current setup: https://gist.github.com/mindscratch/22d507f8401dc9f78627db8c61b3f931 
The docs show the component using the props selector directly, which is a bit different from how I have things setup.

Comment: props have been deprecated, I found the following comment by @timdeschryver to be very helpful in converting to factory selectors: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2980#issuecomment-819551245

Comment: Selectors with props will be deprecated in ngrx v12. https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v12

Answer (score 16):

You could use the projector function:

```
export interface Record {
  // Some sort of record interface
}

export interface State {
  records: Record[];
}

export const getRecords = createSelector(
  getState,
  (state: State): Record[] => state.records)
);

export const getRecordByIndex = createSelector(
  getRecords,
  (records: Record[], { index }) => records[index]),
);

export const getFirstRecord = createSelector(
  getRecords,
  (records: Record[]) => getRecordByIndex.projector(records, { index: 0 })
);
```

Comment: This is the only answer to the actual question, all the others miss the point. The downside of this solution is that `getFirstRecord` has to know the input selector `getRecords` of `getRecordByIndex` in order to pass the state on to the projector function. The implementation of `getRecordByIndex` is leaking into `getFirstRecord`.

Answer (score 12):

I am using `"@ngrx/entity": "7.2.0",` and I can see that props are passed to each selector, for example in my component I am calling:

```
this.isActive$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromClient.isActive, { id: 'someid' }));
```

And then in my reducer I have the following:

```
export const getState = createFeatureSelector('state');

export const getEntity = createSelector(
  getState,
  (state, props) => {
    // do something with props.id to get an entity then:
    return state;
  }
);

export const isActive: = createSelector(
  getEntity, // props are passed to here
  (state: any) => { // i don't add the props argument here, as i don't need them
    return state.isActive;
  }
);
```

Comment: Just verified this works with current stable @ngrx v10.

Answer (score 11):

This can be done with "factory selectors" as described by @timdeschryver in his [comment regarding the deprecation of `props` from ngrx selectors](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2980#issuecomment-819551245).

Using the OP's request, I would have the following implementation:

```js
export const getRecordByIndex = (index: number) => createSelector(
   getRecords, (records) => records[index]
);
```

That could then be used as:

```js
const record$ = this.store.select(getRecordByIndex(1));
```

This seems to be the preferred way now that "Using selectors with props" is marked as [Deprecated in the ngrx documentation](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#using-selectors-with-props).

Comment: But what if `index` parameter is a variable (e.g., user text input value), the factory selector would not be updated with the new `index` value?

Answer (score 8):

I managed to provide parameters to the selector with a slight change on how I use it. Example:

#### selector (I do not use a separate feature here)

```
export const selectReferentialsState = (state: AppState) => state.referentials;

export const referentialDataSelector = createSelector(
    selectReferentialsState,
    (state: ReferentialsState, props: { refType: Referential}) => state.data[props.refType]
);
```

#### usage

```
this.availableRoles$ = this.store.select(state => referentialDataSelector(state, { refType: Referential.Role}));
```

---

#### Advanced usage (cascade selectors with parameters)

I will provide another example to cover the more complex scenario of having to define a selector that relies on a selector that requires parameters (`props`). This also includes an easier usage syntax (`pipe` + `select`):

```
export const selectQuestionnaireTranslationInfo = createSelector(
    selectQuestionnaireTranslationState,
    (state: QuestionnaireTranslationState, props: { formId: number}) => state.entities[props.formId]
);

export const selectQuestionnaireLanguageProgress = createSelector(
    selectQuestionnaireTranslationInfo,
    (state: QuestionnaireTemplateTranslationFullInfo, props: {formId: number, langId: number }) =>
        state?.languageInfo?.find(li => li.spTranslationLanguageId === props.langId)
);

export const selectQuestionnaireLanguageProgressCount = createSelector(
    selectQuestionnaireLanguageProgress,
    (state: QuestionnaireTemplateTranslationLanguageInfo) =>
        state?.translatedResourceCount
);
```

Usage:

```
const props = { formId: this.templateId, langId: this.languageId};
this.progressCount$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectQuestionnaireLanguageProgressCount, props));`
```

As already noted by [Ian Jamieson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56267891/2780791), props are merged and available in the selectors chain (that's why the last selector does not require to explicitly declare the props, they are "inherited").

Comment: great to see your usage section

Comment: This should be in the docs... typed props and information where to get the `state` from!

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass the index as a parameter.

In selector file

```
export const getRecordByIndex = (index)=> createSelector(
getRecords,
(records) => records[index])
);
```

In component

```
this.store.select(getRecordByIndex(0)).subscribe(res=> {  //pass your index
    res; // your output 
});
```

you can check this blog https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/parameterized-selectors

Answer (score 1):

There is a better alternative proposed by `@timdeschryver` [here](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2980#issuecomment-819551245):

```js
export const hasRight = (rightCode: RightCode) => createSelector(selectUser, (user) => {
    return user?.rights?.indexOf(rightCode) !== -1;
});

// you can consume it as
const canEditClient$ = this.store.select(hasRight(RIGHT_EDIT_CLIENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

use mapSelectors from this library [reselect-mapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reselect-mapper)

see the example bellow

```
import { mapSelectors } from "reselect-mapper"

const getUserById = (state: State, id: string) => state.users[id]
const getPostByIndex = (state: State, index: number) => state.posts[index]

// now you can combine your selectors using mapSelectors
const getUserAndPost = mapSelectors({
         user: getUserById,
         post: getPostByIndex
      }, map => map); // map signature is { user: User, post: Post }
// getUserAndPost selector has the following signature
// (state: State, params: { user: string, post: number }) => ({ user: User, post: Post })
```