# Composing selectors in ngrx store with entities

Tags: angular, typescript, store, ngrx, ngrx-entity

I am currently working on an ngrx store project using ngrx entites in which I would like to compose some selectors, like this:

```
export const selectProductById = (productId: number) => createSelector(
  selectProductState,
  productsState => productsState.entities[productId]
);

export const selectCurrentProduct = createSelector(
  selectProductState,
  productsState => productsState.entities[productsState.selectedProductId]
);
```

I would like to use the `selectProductById` selector in the `selectCurrentProduct` selector, like this:

```
// doesn't work
export const selectCurrentProduct = createSelector(
  selectProductState,
  productsState => selectProductById(productsState.selectedProductId)
);
```

What would be the syntax? This causes compilation errors where I try to use the `selectCurrentProduct` selector:

> Type 'Observable<emoizedSelector<object, Product>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Product>'

## Update

Thanks for all the links and stuff, but they don't really address my problem. I am looking to create a selector using `createSelector()` using another selector, also created by `createSelector()`. Please see my pseudocode above. I am trying to use te `selectProductById` using the `selectProductById` selector.

Comment: This might help you with some ideas around parameterized selectors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53546085/ngrx-how-to-pass-parameters-to-selector-inside-createselector-method/53546233#53546233, if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ngrx: how to pass parameters to selector inside createSelector method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53546085/ngrx-how-to-pass-parameters-to-selector-inside-createselector-method)