# Difference between constructor function and a function that creates an object

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between a constructor function that creates an object like this:

```js
function User(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.isAdmin = false;
}

let user = new User("Jack");
```

and a non constructor function that looks like this:

```js
function user(name, age) {
  return {
    name,
    age,
  }
};

let user = user("Tom", 23);
```

I am currently learning about constructor functions and it does not make sense for me to use them if you can replace them with the function above. Can anybody explain how a constructor function is more useful in practise?

Comment: One useful feature is easy “type” checks: `user instanceof User`. There’s also inheritance, but this could be implemented like `function cat(){ return {...animal(), noise: "meow"}; }`.

Comment: If it helps, I've posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53927681/5217142) to the older question using your examples.