# Extended Class methods are not exposed

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, ecmascript-6

I am trying to extend a class in javascript and add some extra functions to that class.

```
const Pino = require('pino');

class Logger extends Pino {
  constructor(options = { name: 'isWorking' }) {
    super(options);
    this.check = "1234";
    this.ppp = () => {}
  }

  rrr() {}
}

let pp = new Logger();
console.log(pp.check)
console.log(pp.ppp)
console.log(pp.rrr)
console.log(pp instanceof Logger)
console.log(pp instanceof Pino)
```

This is the output

```
1234
[Function]
undefined
false
false
```

Why is that `rrr` function is not exposed ? i thought of overriding the base class. This should be working for normal class, what special about this `Pino` class ?

Note: Here pino base class is javascript module

- https://github.com/pinojs/pino/blob/master/pino.js

Thanks,

Comment: Cannot reproduce. https://jsfiddle.net/x3gse5ja/ Post the code of Pino if you want it to be able to be debugged.

Comment: Please post the code of `Pino`. Maybe it returns a plain object, not a proper instance? You can check whether `pp instanceof Logger` (probably `false`) and whether `pp instanceof Pino`.

Comment: @Bergi Edited the question with your inputs

Comment: @CertainPerformance Edited the question with your inputs

Comment: If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself*

Comment: [Wow](https://github.com/pinojs/pino/blob/master/lib/proto.js#L37-L38)

Comment: @Bergi may i know what is intention for that const constructor = class Pino {}.

Comment: @Sathish Satire. It makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the clarification.  Can you please also upvote the question. i will make sure create a issue on github based on this discussion.

Comment: @Bergi https://github.com/pinojs/pino/pull/433#pullrequestreview-127703127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the definition of `Pino` (`pino` in the module) does not return an instance of `pino` but a synthesised object -- it has a `return instance` statement at the end.

Although that returned object has received a specific prototype, it is not `pino.prototype`.

So when an instance of `Logger` is created, it also returns this "foreign" object while `rrr` remains "orphaned" on the unused `Logger.prototype`.

See this simplified demo:

```js
function Pino() { return new Date(); }

class Logger extends Pino {
    rrr() { return 1; }
}

const a = new Pino;
const b = new Logger;

console.log(a instanceof Pino); // false
console.log(b instanceof Logger); // false
console.log(b instanceof Pino); // false
console.log(b instanceof Date); // true

console.log(typeof b.rrr); // undefined
```

If `pino` would just return a proper instance (`this`), then `rrr` would be available:

```js
function Pino() {  } // returns `this`

class Logger extends Pino {
    rrr() { return 1; }
}

const a = new Pino;
const b = new Logger;

console.log(a instanceof Pino); // true
console.log(b instanceof Logger); // true
console.log(b instanceof Pino); // true
console.log(b instanceof Date); // false (obviously)

console.log(typeof b.rrr); // function
```

### Ugly work around

If you really need the extension, then it can be done like this, but it would be better to ask the library author to make their classes extensible:

```js
function Pino() { return new Date(); }

function PinoClass() {} // Don't define anything in this class
PinoClass.prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(new Pino);

class Logger extends PinoClass {
    rrr() { return 1; }
}

const a = new Pino;
const b = new Logger;

console.log(a instanceof Pino); // false
console.log(b instanceof Logger); // true
console.log(b instanceof Pino); // false
console.log(b instanceof Date); // true

console.log(typeof b.rrr); // function
```

Comment: Hi trincot, can you please explain more about this or point me to alink or something. If possible may i know to extend that module in any other way ?

Comment: Even if it was `pino.prototype` (which would help with `instanceof pino`), that wouldn't allow extending the "class".

Comment: @Sathish I would recommend to open a Github issue with a feature request to make the library extensible. The authors will tell you how best to do it, tell you not to do it at all but use a different mechanism for customisation, or might release a new version of the library that does allow subclassing.

Comment: I added some snippets.

Comment: Trincot thanks for the detailed example. Can you please also upvote the question. i will make sure create a issue on github based on this discussion.

Comment: @Sathish, I added a work-around to my answer. But it's ugly.

Answer (score 4):

Note: I am a maintainer of Pino.

The function returned by `require('pino')` is a [factory function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698726/constructor-function-vs-factory-functions) not a "constructor" function. As such, the `class` sugar syntax will not work for customizing the Pino prototype: we do not expose the prototype.

To customize Pino one would wrap an instance with their own functionality:

```
const instance = require('pino')()
Object.defineProperties(instance, {
  rrr: {
    value: function () {
      this.info('this is the rrr function')
    }
  }
})

instance.rrr()
```

I highly recommend learning about the way objects in Javascript really work instead of relying on the (in my opinion disastrous) `class` syntax. [The Two Pillars of Javascript](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/the-two-pillars-of-javascript-ee6f3281e7f3) is an excellent set of articles on the subject. And the [You Don't Know JS: `this` & Object Prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes) is a great in-depth book on the subject.