# Why do objects in the Chrome console appear different when using a factory function vs a constructor function?

Tags: javascript

Given the following code (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8699045/13468777)):

```js
function ConstructorFunction() {
    this.someProp1 = "cf1";
    this.someProp2 = "cf2";
}
ConstructorFunction.prototype.someMethod = function () { /* whatever */ };

function factoryFunction() {
    var obj = {
        someProp1: "ff1",
        someProp2: "ff2",
        someMethod: function () { /* whatever */ }
    };
    // other code to manipulate obj in some way here
    return obj;
}

let objFromConstructor = new ConstructorFunction()
let objFromFactory = factoryFunction()

console.log(objFromConstructor)
console.log(objFromFactory)
```

I get different looking objects in the Chrome console:

[image]

There is text (ConstructorFunction) before the constructor function object - what is this called?

Why is the object from the factory function missing this text?

Does the difference in structure affect anything about how these objects will work?

Comment: Yes the console shows you that the first object is an instance of the ConstructorFunction class, the second object is not an instance of that class so you don't see that label, you can see the difference in methods, the first object has access to that method via it's Contructor prototype, but the second object has the method on it...

Comment: @SaymoinSam Technically, JavaScript doesn't have classes (nor instance of classes). It has objects. `class` is a syntactic keyword that makes designing prototype objects simpler.

Comment: Yes I know, it's a prototype based programming language, I jsut prefer to say class although it's not a class, it's only ES6 syntax... and instance, just so he can understand, but behind the hood it's the same old behaviour.

Comment: I'm sure there are other implications but if you add this to the factory they print the same thing `Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, ConstructorFunction.prototype);`  More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is text (ConstructorFunction) before the constructor function
>   object - what is this called?

`ConstructorFunction` is the name of your instance object, while with the factory, there is no instance, just an object literal, so no name to report.

> Does the difference in structure affect anything about how these
>   objects will work?

Absolutely. The constructor version has `this` context pointing to each instance generated, while the factory doesn't and the constructor forms the basis of an inheritance chain that is highly configurable, while the factory doesn't.

Comment: `this context pointing to each instance generated, while the factory doesn't` - this is not true. The behavior of `this` is resolved at method call time so both `this` points to the instances

Comment: @slebetman You misunderstand my point. *Within* the function, `this` binding is different, which is why it's used in the Constructor and not in the Factory. Within the Factory, `this` could be anything, while within the Constructor, `this` is pointed to the future instance.

Comment: Also not true. In the object created by the constructor the behavior of `this` does not depend on the constructor, instead it depends on how you call the method. An object created with a constructor can have the `this` be anything. Yes **within** the constructor `this` is the instance as in within the call of the constructor until the end of the constructor function. But this does not mean that `this` in methods is bound in a special way from object literals. If you mean within the constructor call then yes but your answer does not say that.

Comment: *Yes within the constructor this is the instance as in within the call of the constructor until the end of the constructor function.* <-- And that's all I've been saying. I don't know why you keep arguing points I haven't made.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome tries to guess what is the object's constructor. In other languages this is called the object's **class** and you can sort of call it that especially with modern class-based syntax.

When you create an empty object using the object literal syntax, `{}`, the class of the object is merely `Object` (yes, there is literally a constructor function in js called Object). When this happens Chrome does not print the class name.

The main difference is that the first object has a constructor and the second does not. Generally this has no effect on how the object behaves except when you use features to ask about the object itself. One difference you have noticed is that the object logged by Chrome is displayed differently by the debugging console.

Other differences include the fact that `objFromConstructor` is an `instanceof` `ConstructorFunction` and also an `instanceof` `Object` but `objFromFactory` is only `instanceof` `Object`. You can think of the `instanceof` operator as telling you if an object is of a particular type so you can say that `objFromConstructor` is a type of `ConstructorFunction` but `objFromFactory` is not. Note that all objects inherit form `Object` so all objects are also of type `Object`.

In general, unless you are doing some metaprogramming/introspection/reflection by using things like `instanceof` you will not notice any difference between the two.

Comment: Note that this example illustrates why names like `ConstructorFunction` is a bad name for a constructor/class because you can say that `objFromConstructor` is a type of `ConstructorFunction` but it is not a function which is what I would expect an object of type `ConstructorFunction` to be (note that there is a real-world example of an object type being called a function: `React.FunctionComponent` which is a type of function)

Comment: *In other languages this is called the object's class* <-- In modern class-based OOP languages, it's called the "super-class", "base class, or "parent class', not the object's class.