# What is the difference between a constructor function and function returning an object?

Tags: javascript, function, object, constructor

How are they different and why would you use one over the other?

For example:

```js
function setupOptionsObj(num) {
  return {
    data: num,
    func: function() {
      return num * 10
    }
  }
}

function setupOptionsConstructor(num) {
  this.data = num;
  this.func = function() {
    return num * 10
  }
}

var one = setupOptionsObj(123)
var two = new setupOptionsConstructor(123)

console.log(one.func());
console.log(two.func());
```

Thank you :)

Comment: The difference is prototype inheritance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constructor function vs Factory functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698726/constructor-function-vs-factory-functions)

Answer (score 2):

`setupOptionsObj()` returns a plain object.

`new setupOptionsConstructor()` returns an object whose prototype is `setupOptionsConstructor.prototype`.

Prototypes allow you to add methods and properties that apply to all objects created by that constructor. This is the basis of JavaScript's prototype-based object-oriented programming.

For example, below we only have one `foo` function, not one in every object.

```js
function setupOptionsConstructor(num) {
  this.data = num;
}

setupOptionsConstructor.prototype.func = function() {
  return this.data * 10
};

var two = new setupOptionsConstructor(123);
var three = new setupOptionsConstructor(456);

console.log(two.func());
console.log(three.func());
```